# How to watch a URL using Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am suppose to watch this URL for modifications

http://redsismica.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt

It is a text file that is updated. I would like to monitor it for changes using the request module in nodejs.

How do I do it?

Comment: I can't answer your question because it's been closed... but just make a `HEAD` request and compare the `ETag` to the last `ETag`.  Really though, what you're asking to do is cache data locally.  The `Cache-Control` header for this URL indicates that you shouldn't cache it, so if you do, be aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want so I'll show you maybe the simplest way to do this using the [request.js](https://github.com/request/request) framework and an simple Node.js [setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg) and [clearInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_clearinterval_intervalobject).

```
var request = require('request');
var catalogue;

var checkCatalogue = function() {
    request('http://redsismica.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          if(!catalogue){
            catalogue = body;
          } else {
                // here you should do a complex verification, for example check line by line...
                if(catalogue === body) {
                    console.log('everything is equal');
                } else {
                    console.log('something is different');
                    // stop the interval to do something (if you needed)
                    clearInterval(checkCatalogue);
                    //...
                    // do what you want to do with the catalogue 
                }

          }
      }
    });
}

// execute checkCatalogue function once per second
setInterval(checkCatalogue, 1000);
```

This is only an example that can open your mind for a way to solve your issue. I can't test my code because I don't have the Node.js installed in my PC :(
But the idea behind of my suggestion is you can use a timer function to check from time to time what changed in the catalogue file.